# Threads did not exit in parallel execution in karate

Tags: karate

Here is my code snippet for parallel execution:

```
package examples;
import com.intuit.karate.KarateOptions;
import com.intuit.karate.Results;
import com.intuit.karate.Runner;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import org.junit.Test;

@KarateOptions(tags = {"~@ignore"})
public class ExamplesTest {

     @Test
        public void testParallel() {
            List<String> tags = Arrays.asList("~@ignore");
            List<String> features = Arrays.asList("classpath:examples/autocomment"); 
            Results results = Runner.parallel(tags,features, 5, "target/surefire-reports");
           // assertTrue(results.getErrorMessages(), results.getFailCount() == 0);
        }
}
```

Once all feature files executed using command 
`mvn test -DargLine="-Dkarate.env=qa"`,threads did not exit and hence build never gets concluded.
Could you please let me know if I am doing anything wrong here??
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of your tests probably has a severe error (maybe the eval of `karate-config.js`). Run using the JUnit runner and see the logs.

This should be fixed in this ticket, do see if you can build from source and validate: https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/667

Comment: There is no any server error but still threads are not getting exit.I have two feature files which have tag ignore as I am calling them from another feature files.so when I checked reports then I observed for all feature files,it created three files as .log, .xml and .json .But for feature files with tag ignore it creates only .log files.Is is reason that threads are not getting exit??

Comment: @swapna no they will just be empty.

Comment: Got compilation error while building source code mentioned in https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/Developer-Guide as "class file has wrong version 55.0, should be 52.0 Please remove or make sure it appears in the correct subdirectory of the classpath. [ERROR] /karate/karate-core/src/main/java/com/intuit/karate/StepActions.java:[150,13] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] /home/sgadkari/NotBackedUp/karate/karate-core/src/main/java/com/intuit/karate/StepActions.java:[161,13] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]/karate/karate-core/src/main/java/com/intuit/karate/StepActions.java:[330,13] cannot find symbol

Comment: @swapna um, get someone who knows java + maven well to help you, all the best !